# React-Navigation: Reducer not getting called

Tags: react-redux, react-navigation

**Background:**
I'm making a React-Native app. 
I have found this boilerplate: https://github.com/ipeedy/react-native-boilerplate
Since it was a bit old, I updated all dependencies and made a PR. So contributing to open-source projects felt so nice, that since I need localization in my project, I would make it in the boilerplate and add that as a PR as well.

**Goal:**
I wanted to implement https://github.com/joshswan/react-native-globalize and all that seems to be working great when I manually in the code changes the language code on the top level component.
So now I wanted to just make a button which could change the language code. Just as a test before I implement a select list the correct place.

**Issue:**
So, I've really tried to look for the answer on how to get my Redux together in this boilerplate, but I can only get my action to run but nothing else happens.

I'm still learning react, but I think I have a pretty good understanding of it, but for Redux - I'm still a noob :)

All my code is here: https://github.com/AndersGerner/react-native-boilerplate on the master branch.

Here is the pieces of the code that does not work:

```
...
import { changeLanguage } from '../actions'
...
class WelcomeScreen extends Component {
    render() {
    return (
      <ContainerView>
        <TitleText>
                  <FormattedMessage
            message="Welcome"
          />
                  </TitleText>
        <ButtonContainer>
          <Button text="Go to main" onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Main')} />
                    <Button text="Set lang to DK - Directly" onPress={() => {changeLanguage('DK')}} />
                    <Button text="Set lang to DK - Dispatch" onPress={() => {this.props.navigation.dispatch({type:'change_language'})}} />
        </ButtonContainer>
      </ContainerView>
    );
  }
}
```

**SOURCE:** https://github.com/AndersGerner/react-native-boilerplate/blob/master/src/screens/Welcome.js

So I have the understanding that calling the action directly just gives me the returned object, and therefor nothing happens. 
But I have then tried to make a 3. button which uses the "Dispatch" function through react-navigation which I have read is using the default Redux dispatch function and should be the right way to do it.

As it can be seen in my code in the repo, I have added console.logs in both the action and the reducers.

My output is:
Calling the action directly resolves in the console.log being fired.
Using the dispatch function does NOT show any logs or anything.

Thank you all very much in advance for any help given :)

Answer (score 0):

So.. I learned about connect :)

For anyone who stops by, the problem was solved but adding this to the bottom of my WelcomeScreen file:

```
const mapStateToProps = state => ({ });

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {
    changeLanguage,
})(WelcomeScreen);
```

:)